# CMake: Is there anyway to force linking libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, cmake

Is there anyway to force linking libraries again. This would be useful when some libraries have changed but there is no change in any of the source codes of current project. I am looking for something like this:

> make link

Comment: You could remove one object file then run `make` again

Comment: Or remove all the libs/dlls in your build dir if Basile's option does not work and run make again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake should be able to relink automatically when a particular library changes if you follow the tips here: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-November/041072.html

The main idea is to give a full path to target_link_libraries(), rather than just the library name.  If you give a full path, CMake will actually inspect the file for modification and relink if it has changed.

If you prefer to explicitly trigger relinking yourself, you can use add_custom_command to make a command like `make link` which will remove the executable and then trigger a regular `make` to rebuild it.

Comment: note: be sure to place the 'lib' prefix to the library name; I forgot this and got errors that took me a while to fix ;-)